# Localization of Settings strings in IOS

Tags: ios, localization

I have successfully localized the strings in my code .m file by creating Localizable.strings files located in their appropriate xx.proj groups. The Localizable.strings files also contain localizations of the strings used in the Settings.bundle

When I run my iPad application in the IOS Simulator localizations work OK except the localization of strings in my Settings, which are defined in the Settings.bundle / Root.plist. Strings in the Settings remain in English. I have been unable to find the Apple document dealing with the localization of strings in the Settings.bundle.

Obviously, thousands of developers have done this before, but I am stuck.

---

Problem solved.
How I added localization files to Settings.bundle.

1. In Xcode did a show in Finder for Settings.bundle.
2. In Finder selected Settings.bundle, and selected Show Package Contents.
3. Created a xx.lproj folder in the Finder
4. Created UTF-16 file with Settings localization (xx country). Saved it as Root.strings in the xx.lproj folder.
5. Copied existing .storyboard file (xx country) into xx.lproj folder.
6. Copied existing Localizable.strings file (xx country) into Xx.lproj folder.
7. Checked that Root.plist contanined Strings Filename == Root.strings.

Repeated 1-6 for other country localizations.

Comment: If I have two languages then - 1. there would be 4 .storyboard, right? 2. How would I keep image folders for both selection type?